# Meaning of "Cracked" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

On the other side of the room, Miles hit the button that automatically unlocked the front door. **Then cracked the one leading into the building**, the sound of heavy footfalls climbing the steps.

What i got is that means the sound of how he lead into the building?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**crack the door**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/43632?rskey=P30jcv&result=1&isAdvanced=true#eid7941043)  definition and an example use:

- > 1964   Spectator 14 Feb. 205   Mr. Kennedy..made it his practice..to
  >   leave the door to his office cracked a little so that any personal
  >   assistant who felt the need to talk to him might walk right in.

definition:

> trans and intrans. Of a door: to be slightly ajar; to leave slightly
>   ajar. Cf. crack n. 7d. Chiefly U.S.

Here is another figurative use:

> The door cracked open for the Dodgers in the seventh inning Friday
>   when Sean Doolittle, not Stephen Strasburg, appeared on the mound at
>   Dodger Stadium.  Los Angeles TimesOct 4, 2019

Comment: As a BrE speaker, I haven't heard this specific use before. Doors can have a crack, but I wouldn't crack it open.

Comment: Having 'the one' refer to 'door' when 'button' is indicated is at best clumsy.

Comment: @lbf Thanks! Could you explain a little more about "the one' here too? refers to what?

Comment: another door ...